# Can I not use contains operator on a collection assigned to a variable?

Tags: drools

I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me why this is illegal:

```
rule "some rule name"

when 
    $a : A($bset : bset)
    $bset contains B(x == "hello")
then
    //do something
end
```

Where:

```
public class A {
private Set<B> bset = new HashSet<B>();
//getters and setters for bset
//toString() and hashCode for A

public static class B {
private String x
//getters and setters for x
//toString() and hashCode() for B
}
}
```

The error from the Drools eclipse plugin is not very helpful.  It provides the following error:

[ERR 102] Line 23:16 mismatched input 'contains' in rule "some rule name"

The error appears on the line with "bset contains..."

I have searched through the Drools documentation, as well as a book that I have, and have not found the examples to be very illustrative in this regard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'contains' is an operator that must be used inside a pattern. `$bset contains B(x == "hello")` is not a valid pattern in this case. 
There are a couple of ways to achieve what you are trying to do. This is one of them:

```
rule "some rule name"
when 
    $a: A($bset : bset)
    $b: B(x == "hello") from $bset
then
    //you will have one activation for each of the B objects matching 
    //the second pattern
end
```

Another:

```
rule "some rule name"
when 
    $a: A($bset : bset)
    exists (B(x == "hello") from $bset)
then
    //you will have one activation no matter how many B objects match 
    //the second pattern ( you must have at least one of course)
end
```

If you want to see how `contains` operation is used, and if the B objects are also facts in your session, you can write something like this:

```
rule "some rule name"
when 
    $b: B(x == "hello")
    $a: A(bset contains $b)
then
    //multiple activations
end
```

or:

```
rule "some rule name"
when 
    $b: B(x == "hello")
    exists( A(bset contains $b) )
then
    //single activation
end
```

Hope it helps,